# USB Notifications - Turn Off - Ubuntu 18

Tags: usb, notification

I have a permanent USB drive notification, how can I get rid of it, prevent it from popping back up.  It takes up Screen space,... I know I have a USB drive!

Comment: Hmmm. My USB drive notifications properly vanish after a few seconds. Did you perhaps change your notification settings?

Comment: I've tried to turn them off, under Notifications->'Notification Popups' are disabled, and this is ignored